# socket.io without node js ? I can;t run node js server from my cpanel

Tags: node.js, socket.io

i want to put a realtime chat for my online users on my webpage using Sockets.io and node js, but i don't know how to do that bcz in my cpanel hosting account i don't have a bash to run commands, is there a way to run node js if i don't have the bash terminal in my cpanel?